# Conditional loop through dataframe rows with last non NAN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python :)

I have the following dataframe, some columns are without header:

[image]

I am trying to do pretty basic condition for each name: like if dinner print "Good Evening".

What I did so far is trying to find the last non NAN values for each row:

```
df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Result:

```
0       dinner
1        lunch
2       dinner
3        lunch
4    breakfast
5        lunch
6        lunch
7       dinner
Name: Unnamed: 11, dtype: object
```

Then trying to carry out the condition using for:

```
for index, column in df.iterrows():
        if df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1] == "dinner":
            print ("Good evening",column['Name'])
```

I got this error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I then tried:

```
for i in df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]:
    if i == "dinner":
        print ("Good evening",column['Name'])
```

But the condition does not work as expected!

```
Good evening Sara
Good evening Sara
Good evening Sara
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you create code that will generate our input dataframe?

Comment: Related: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html#pandas-dataframe-last-valid-index) is also an option:

```
m = df.apply(lambda s: s[s.last_valid_index()], axis=1).eq('dinner')

for name in df.loc[m, 'Name']:
    print('Good evening', name)
```

```
Good evening Sara
Good evening Remon
Good evening Alber
```

---

Or create a new series:

```
m = df.apply(lambda s: s[s.last_valid_index()], axis=1).eq('dinner')

print('Good evening ' + df.loc[m, 'Name'])
```

```
0     Good evening Sara
2    Good evening Remon
3    Good evening Alber
Name: Name, dtype: object
```